# Probability of Winning the Lottery

Tags: probability

Lets say there are 200 tickets in a lottery system. Six tickets are drawn one by one, without replacement. These six tickets win a prize. Lets say you bought 1 ticket, what is the probability that you win a prize?

The obvious answer would just be 6/200 = 3%, but isn't it more than that since the odds of winning get better every ticket draw? (1/200 for first ticket, 1/199 for second, etc...) This would make sense, but the idea fails when you use it for a scenario with 5 tickets and 4 winning draws. P(winning) would then be 1/5 + 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2, but that value is bigger than 1.

Not sure where I'm missing something here... The problem seems so simple but I just made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Your probaility of winning on the second draw is $\frac{199}{200}\cdot \frac{1}{199}$, which is $\frac{1}{200}$. This is in retrospect obvious. Similarly, we could find the probability of winning on the third draw the hard way. It is $\frac{199}{200}\cdot\frac{198}{199}\cdot \frac{1}{198}$. But I prefer the easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis overcounts the probability of winning the lottery from the second ticket on.  You say the probability of winning with the second ticket is $1/199$, but that's only true if the first ticket doesn't win.  If the first ticket does win, the probability of winning with the second ticket is *zero*.  If you compute the expected probability of winning with the second ticket, you get

$$
P(\text{win with second ticket})
    = \frac{199}{200}\times\frac{1}{199}+\frac{1}{200}\times 0 = \frac{1}{200}
$$

You can come up with corresponding analyses for the third through sixth tickets.

Another way to approach the problem, sequentially, is to consider the probability that you don't win with *any* of the six tickets, and then subtract that from one to get the probability that you *do* win.  Then

$$
P(\text{lose}) = \frac{199}{200} \times \frac{198}{199} \times \frac{197}{198}
                                 \times \cdots \times \frac{194}{195}
               = \frac{194}{200} = \frac{97}{100}
$$

and then $P(\text{win}) = 1-P(\text{lose}) = 3/100$.

Comment: Given your method, wouldn't P(win with second ticket) be equal to 1/200 + 199/200 * 1/199? which is 2/200 instead of 1/200? I'm not sure where the 0 came from.

Comment: The zero came from the reasoning in the very first paragraph: If the first ticket does win (probability $1/200$) then the probability of winning with the second ticket is zero (the $0$).  You're multiplying it effectively by $1$, which is equivalent to saying that if you win with the first ticket, you are guaranteed to also win with the second ticket.  Doesn't that sound a bit odd to you?

Comment: So basically, there's no difference in probability between:
1. Drawing all 6 tickets one at a time with replacement.
2. Drawing all 6 tickets all at once in the beginning.

The probability of winning is the same in each case?

Comment: Difference in the probability of what?  The *a priori* probability of winning with the second ticket is the same in either case: $1/200$.  However, the probability of winning at all in six tickets is different.  In the problem as described in your question, it is just $3/100$, as you determined.  If you were to replace each ticket as it was drawn, the probability of winning (at least) once is $1-(199/200)^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Your chance of winning with the second draw is not always $\frac1{199}$. If you already won with the first draw, your chance to win (also) with thesecond draw is $0$.